# Wordpress Microsites for clients

Tags: wordpress, templates, inheritance, content-management-system

The company I work for want to switch from their custom CMS to Wordpress. Our clients are mostly hotels and need microsites for things like languages and a dedicated golf site.

Currently their CMS is able to set up microsites with it's own css that's inherited to it's subpages. Is it possible to have the template inherited to subpages?

It also has options that only affect the microsite (e.g. the main slider images can be changed for the whole microsite or on a per page basis). The clients need to ability to add pages, change options and change content per microsite.

We need to implement this kind of functionality in Wordpress. Does anyone know if this is possible or can you point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible as you can choose which template to use in multisite.

For multiple slider locations, you can use widgets if you need a slider for sitewide or use page level options if you want the slider only on specific pages.

There are a lot of plugins available to customize WordPress and you will start loving Wordpress once you start using it.

Comment: Thanks for you're reply, is it possible to set a template on a page and have all its subpages inherit it's template?

Comment: You can set a template on the page. However, there is not a direct way to inherit the parent page template on subpages. You can do it with custom coding.